# Type.AssemblyQualifiedName for fields

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, fieldinfo

Is there a way to get something like the `Type.AssemblyQualifiedName` property, which differentiates between a List of strings and a List of bytes, from a `System.Reflection.FieldInfo`?

`The FieldInfo.GetFullName()` method doesn't differentiate between the 2, and I need to be able to get the offset of a field, and still differentiate between List of strings and a List of bytes.

Comment: That's a bit unclear.  I assume you're looking for FieldInfo.FieldType

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could access the field's type by looking at the `FieldType` property of your `FieldInfo` object.

EDIT

I stand corrected. `Type.Name` will not do what you want. You could use `Type.AssemblyQualifiedName` as you suggest or you could access the types directly by looking at the result of `Type.GetGenericArguments()`.